# Manual color scale with Plotly table values in Python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm creating a simple table like this...

```
trace = go.Table(
      header = dict(
        #some header info
      ),
      cells = dict(
        values = weeklyIntegers, #list e.g. [4, 11, 0, 32]
        line = dict(color = '#506784'),
        font = dict(color = '#506784', size = 9)
       ),
    )
    plotyData.append(trace)

layout = go.Layout(
    #some layout info
)

fig = Figure(data=plotyData, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='someFilename')
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to apply a simple color scale to the cell values **without using a library like colorlover** as [suggested here](https://plot.ly/python/table/) (the reason is that I don't have control of the enivornment to install new libraries).

Shouldn't I be able to pass a list of pre-determined colors to the font definition in cells like...

```
myColorList = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow']
cells = dict(
        values = weeklyIntegers, #list e.g. [4, 11, 0, 32]
        line = dict(color = '#506784'),
        font = dict(color = myColorList, size = 9)
       ),
```

I can't find any documentation tackling this so at this point am just guessing about what the appropriate syntax is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `from plotly.colors import n_colors` you can build your own color scale that will be more flexible with regards to the length of your `weeklyIntegers` list. Below is a plot that uses a blue color, but I've set up two variables for red and green as well.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.colors import n_colors
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# color scale
a = [4, 11, 0, 32]
blues = n_colors('rgb(200, 200, 255)', 'rgb(0, 0, 200)', max(a)+1, colortype='rgb')
reds = n_colors('rgb(255, 200, 255)', 'rgb(200, 0, 0)', max(a)+1, colortype='rgb')
greens = n_colors('rgb(200, 255, 200)', 'rgb(0, 200, 0)', max(a)+1, colortype='rgb')


# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# table setup
tbl = go.Table(header=dict(values=['<b>Table with custom color scale</b>'],
                            line_color='white', fill_color='white',
                            font=dict(color='white', size=8)),
               cells=dict(values=[a],
                            line_color=[np.array(blues)[a]],
                            fill_color=[np.array(blues)[a]],
                            align='center', font=dict(color='white', size=11)))

fig.add_trace(go.Table(tbl))

fig.show()
```